# Find coordinates using Address or location

Tags: iphone

How to find coordinates of gives address (or) location using xcode ?(i.e find latitude/longitude of the specified address)

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advnance........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to is called [geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding). Typically is done by sending a request to a service which actually does the conversion for you. [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) and some other companies offer this service.